# Changing the values in a dictionary (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dictionary that shows the name of the students and their score out of 3.

```
d = {('z', 'b'): 1, ('a', 'd'): 2, ('a', 'f'): 3}
```

I need to change the values for this dictionary (scores) to a percentage and print them.

First, I have to take the scores and changed it to a percentage and I have done that by:

```
numbers_list = []
 for i in values:
     numbers_list.append((i/3)*100)
 print('Numbers in percent: ', numbers_list)
```

And then I have to print the students names with their percent grade like this:

z b 33

a b 66

a f 100

I tried:

```
for name in d:
    print(format_str.format(name[0], name[1], d[name]))
```

but it prints the values I have earlier (scores) not after I computed it resulting on the following output:

z b 1

a b 2

a f 3

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in functions [`keys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), and [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), or [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to access the key-value pairs stored in a dictionary. If you would just like to print the scores in percentage you can do something like this:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print " ".join(key) + " {0} %".format(round(value*100/float(3), 2))
```

If you would like to change the dictionary and store the percentage values instead of the absolute scores, you can do this:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    d[key] = value*100/float(3)
    print " ".join(key) + " {0} %".format(round(d[key], 2))
```

here [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) is used to round off the value to 2 decimal places.